# Node.js/Express - Where to put MySQL connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm learning how to connect to a mysql database using node.js for my first express web application:
http://expressjs.com/guide/database-integration.html#mysql

Where do I put this code in the Express application that I've just generated? Do I just put it in the app.js file?

It seems to me, that if I put it in app.js, the query-data will remain stagnant for all future web-requests. Where should I put this code if each web-request must have current data from the database?

Sorry, I've written other node.js applications, but I'm new with using it as a web server, and I'm totally new to express. I'd appreciate any guidance about where to put things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simplified block of code that I copied over:

```
'use strict';

var mysql     = require('mysql');

var database = {
  initDB: function() {
    this.pool  = mysql.createPool({
      //fill in
    }});
  },

  query: function(query, callback) {
    this.pool.query(query, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        this.initDB();
        //you can call the query again here if you want
      } else {
        callback(res);
      }
    });
  },

  disconnect: function() {
    if (this.pool) {
      this.pool.end();
    }
  }

};

module.exports = database;
```

You can call the initDB() method inside of your server init code, then call query() method whenever you need to make a real query.

Comment: How robust is this? For example, if the database server gets rebooted after the node-http-server is started, will the pool and connection re-establish without having to restart the web application?

Comment: It won't handle the case you just mentioned, however, a quick fix in query() will do. If this.pool.query returns an error, re-call initDB inside the code. See my edit above